# Netlify form dashboard doesn't display input type file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, gatsby, netlify

I'm building a simple website with Gatsby. The website has a form which contains some input fields type text and one input type file.

I'm using styled-component.

```
  const initialState = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    message: "",
    cv: null,
    linkedinUrl: "",
    isSent: false,
    validation: validator.valid(),
  }
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    ...initialState,
  })

  const [isFormSubmitted, setIsFormSubmitted] = useState(false)

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    })
  }

  const handleFileLoad = e => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      cv: e.target.files[0],
    })
  }

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // const { firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber, siteWeb, message } = formData

    const validation = validator.validate(formData)
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      validation,
    })
    setIsFormSubmitted(true)

    if (validation.isValid) {
      const encode = data => {
        console.log(data)
        return Object.keys(data)
          .map(
            key => encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key])
          )
          .join("&")
      }
      fetch(event.target.action, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        body: encode({ "form-name": title, job, ...formData }),
      })
        .then(() => setFormData({ ...initialState, isSent: true }))
        .catch(error => alert(error))
    }
  }

  const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    phoneNumber,
    linkedinUrl,
    message,
    validation,
  } = formData
  // if the form has been submitted at least once, then check validity every time we render
  // otherwise just use what's in state
  const copyData = { ...formData }
  const formValidation =
    isFormSubmitted && !formData.isSent
      ? validator.validate(copyData)
      : validation

  return (
    <FormStyled
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      data-netlify="true"
      name={title}
      method="POST"
      netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
    >
      <Spacer flex="1 1 50%">
        <Input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Prénom"
          value={firstName}
          handleChange={e => handleInputChange(e)}
          name="firstName"
          required
          fullWidth
          id="firstName"
        />
        <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value={title} />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={job}
          name="job"
          id="job"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
        />
        <ValidationMessage isInvalid={formValidation.firstName.isInvalid}>
          {formValidation.firstName.message}
        </ValidationMessage>
      </Spacer>
      <Spacer flex="1 1 50%">
        <Input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Nom"
          value={lastName}
          handleChange={e => handleInputChange(e)}
          name="lastName"
          required
          fullWidth
          id="lastName"
        />
        <ValidationMessage isInvalid={formValidation.lastName.isInvalid}>
          {formValidation.lastName.message}
        </ValidationMessage>
      </Spacer>
      <Spacer flex="1 1 50%">
        <Input
          type="tel"
          placeholder="Téléphone"
          value={phoneNumber}
          handleChange={e => handleInputChange(e)}
          name="phoneNumber"
          fullWidth
          id="phoneNumber"
        />
        <ValidationMessage isInvalid={formValidation.phoneNumber.isInvalid}>
          {formValidation.phoneNumber.message}
        </ValidationMessage>
      </Spacer>
      <Spacer flex="1 1 50%">
        <Input
          type="email"
          placeholder="E-mail"
          value={email}
          handleChange={e => handleInputChange(e)}
          name="email"
          required
          fullWidth
          id="email"
        />
        <ValidationMessage isInvalid={formValidation.email.isInvalid}>
          {formValidation.email.message}
        </ValidationMessage>
      </Spacer>
      <Spacer flex="1 1 auto">
        <Button title="Télécharger votre CV" colors="primary">
          <InputFile type="file" id="cv" onChange={handleFileLoad} name="cv" />
        </Button>
      </Spacer>
      <Spacer flex="1 1 auto">
        <Text>et / ou</Text>
      </Spacer>
      <Spacer className="linkedin-url">
        <Input
          type="url"
          placeholder="Lien de votre profil linkedin"
          value={linkedinUrl}
          handleChange={e => handleInputChange(e)}
          name="linkedinUrl"
          required
          fullWidth
          id="linkedinUrl"
          iconLeft={
            <LogoLinkedin>
              <img src={Lkd} alt="lien Linkedin" />
            </LogoLinkedin>
          }
        ></Input>
      </Spacer>
      <Spacer>
        <Textarea
          type="text"
          placeholder="Votre message..."
          value={message}
          handleChange={e => handleInputChange(e)}
          name="message"
          required
          fullWidth
          id="message"
        />
        <ValidationMessage isInvalid={formValidation.message.isInvalid}>
          {formValidation.message.message}
        </ValidationMessage>
      </Spacer>
      <SuccessMessage isSent={formData.isSent}>
        Merci, votre message a bien été envoyé !
      </SuccessMessage>
      <Spacer textAlign="center">
        <Button title="Envoyer" type="submit" colors="primary" />
      </Spacer>
    </FormStyled>
  )
}
```

Below is the request payload when I send the file :

```
form-name=postuler&job=Tous&firstName=foo&lastName=bar&email=foo.bar%40gmail.com&phoneNumber=0102030405&message=foo%20bar%20baz&cv=%5Bobject%20File%5D&linkedinUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.foobar.fr&isSent=false&validation=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&ignore_whitespace=false&allow_display_name=false&require_display_name=false&allow_utf8_local_part=true&require_tld=true
```

When I send the form, data are correctly displayed in Netlify form dashboard except the content of the input type file which remains empty. I want the content of the input type file to be displayed in Netlify dashboard (Regarding the doc, I assume it should be a link to access the file).

From what I understand looking carefully at the request payload, I'm sending `cv=%5Bobject%20File`, so I guess this the problem, because Netlify could not be able to retrieve the real content of the cv input.

Comment: were you able to fix it ? im having the same problem

Comment: I was not able to fix it and because I was in a rush, instead of storing the file on Netlify I stored it on firebase storage, created a link to access the file remotely and finally added the link to the data sent to Netlify.